# Evento keyPressed con action

Tags: java, java-swing, javafx

Tengo un problema de como realizar el evento correcto hacia dos o tres short-keys con el metodo `getInputMap();`

Estoy realizando un bloc de notas con java swing y estoy con la realización de los atajos de teclado. Mi línea de codigo es: `areaTexto.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), new JFileChooser().showOpenDialog(this));`

Lo que me ocurre es que da igual que no teclee CTRL+A , sino,  que presiono 'A'  y ya me sale la acción, y eso no es lo que quiero.

Tampoco me recoge la acción de tres comandos como : CTRL+SHIFT+S.

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift ctrl pressed S");
```

Y tampoco me funciona, ¿ Me podéis ayudar ?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No se si es la solución, pero curiosamente yo también estoy haciendo un bloc de notas, y en mis atajos la acción de control "sotenido" la tengo como Event.CTRL_MASK. Fijate si asi... ej:  KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, Event.CTRL_MASK); PD: ya que estás haciendo algo parecido, te agradecería si llegas a poder contestar a mi pregunta sobre el tema llegado el momento (si lo llegas a implementar, que aún no sé cómo hacerlo) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/402709/aumentar-tama%c3%b1o-de-texto-en-1-en-jeditorpane-c%c3%b3mo-extraer-el-tama%c3%b1o-del-texto

Comment: La respuesta de abajo, funciona correctamente. Lo he probado y funciona, puede que te sirva a ti también.

Comment: Sisi, pero pense que querías hacerlo mediante el inputMap, a mi me funcionan correctamente y esa es la única diferencia que tengo en los atajos... Luego otros como el copiar cortar y pegar los tengo con el keyListener como te lo ponen abajo. gracias igual por el aviso.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con este código. Lo que hacemos es capturar el evento que nos viene por teclado, mediante un "oyente" en el área de texto.

```
areaTexto.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int ctrlShift = KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK
                    | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK;
            int ctrl = KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK;

            if ((e.getModifiersEx() == ctrl)
                    && (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)) {
                new JFileChooser().showOpenDialog(null);
            } else if ((e.getModifiersEx() & ctrlShift) == ctrlShift
                    && (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
                System.out.println("ctrl + shift + s");
            }
        }
    });
```

Después únicamente tenemos que comprobar qué teclas se han presionado. En el primer caso comprobamos si se ha presionado ctrl y si además, se ha dado a la tecla "A", en caso afirmativo, abriríamos el JFileChooser. En el otro caso, comprobamos que además de ctrl + s también esté pulsado shift.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: No tiene mucha importancia, pero la traducción correcta para _listener_ es _oyente_.

Comment: Cambiado, gracias.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, disculpa la tardanza. Tu código funciona correctamente, me ha ayudado bastante.